# This is a shap function generation code and result of quarter singular element mesh. Is it correct？

Tags: graphs-and-networks, finite-element-method

[image]

[image]

This is a form function generation code and result of quarter singular element mesh. Is it correct？

```
parm = LinearSolve[{f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[7], 
    f[8]}, {u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8}];
f[n_] = {1, Subscript[x, n ], Subscript[y, n ], Subscript[x, n ]^2, 
   Subscript[x, n ]*Subscript[y, n ], Subscript[y, n ]^2, 
   Subscript[y, n ]*Subscript[x, n ]^2, 
   Subscript[x, n ]*Subscript[y, n ]^2};
Subscript[x, 1 ] = 1; Subscript[y, 1 ] = 1;
Subscript[x, 2] = -1; Subscript[y, 2 ] = 1;
Subscript[x, 3 ] = -1; Subscript[y, 3 ] = -1;
Subscript[x, 4 ] = 1; Subscript[y, 4 ] = -1;
Subscript[x, 5 ] = 0; Subscript[y, 5 ] = 1;
Subscript[x, 6 ] = -1; Subscript[y, 6 ] = 0;
Subscript[x, 7 ] = 0.5; Subscript[y, 7 ] = -1;
Subscript[x, 8] = 1; Subscript[y, 8 ] = -0.5;
g = Coefficient[parm, #] &;
formfuction = {g[u1], g[u2], g[u3], g[u4], g[u5], g[u6], g[u7], 
    g[u8]} . {1, x, y, x^2, x*y, y^2, y*x^2, x*y^2};
shapformfuction = formfuction /. Association[{x -> r, y -> s}];
Print["N(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)=", shapformfuction // MatrixForm]
```

Comment: I have edited the title to what I think you want to ask, if this is not correct let me know and I change it back

Comment: What is a 'quater singular element mesh'?

Comment: It's like this picture

Comment: That's a single quad element with mid side nodes moved. Why is this singular? Do you mean single element? Does this mesh have more than one element?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, your method is very good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cross check your shape function with:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
NDSolve`FEM`FindShapeFunction[
 MeshElementBasePolynomial[QuadElement, 2, {r, s}], 
 MeshElementBaseCoordinates[QuadElement, 2], {r, s}]

{-1/4*((-1 + r)*(-1 + s)*(1 + r + s)), ((-1 + s)*(1 - r^2 + s + r*s))/4, 
 ((1 + r)*(1 + s)*(-1 + r + s))/4, ((-1 + r)*(1 + r - s)*(1 + s))/4, 
 ((-1 + r^2)*(-1 + s))/2, -1/2*((1 + r)*(-1 + s^2)), 
 -1/2*((-1 + r^2)*(1 + s)), ((-1 + r)*(-1 + s^2))/2}
```

To find your shape function you replace the `MeshElementBaseCoordinates[QuadElement, 2]` with your coordinates. Incidence ordering is specified on the [`QuadElement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/QuadElement.html) ref page in the details section.

An alternative is that you use the `MeshElementBaseCoordinates[QuadElement, 2]` in your code and reproduce my shape function.